# Where does one find Dungeon World starting materials?

Tags: dungeon-world

> **Prep**
>
> Before the first session, you'll need to print some stuff. Print off:
>
> - A few copies of the basic moves
> - One copy of each class sheet, double-sided
> - One copy of each of the cleric and wizard spell sheets, double-sided
> - The GM sheet

This sure sounds like easy-to-copy or -print materials that we're expected to have on hand, but I can't see where I'd get them. In the book each class description runs *ca.* 7pp.; even with some reduction it's hard to imagine fitting them on a front-back. It sounds from the wording like there're done-up sheets being referenced, but I'm not seeing anything in an appendix or anywhere. Is there a companion website I'm supposed to find?

<strike>The [pdf bundle](http://www.drivethrurpg.com/product/108028/Dungeon-World) didn't have anything like this, either.</strike> (Turns out the .pdf bundle does, but it's really easy to download ten of the twelve .pdfs in the bundle when purchased.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The PDF bundle you linked to includes the *play sheets*, this includes all the items you mentioned in the quoted material in the question. You can also get them (under "Play Kit") from [the Downloads section of the Dungeon World website](http://www.dungeon-world.com/downloads/).

[image: Bundle screenshot]

Comment: Is this answer still accurate? The page linked in the question currently does not list the files shown in this screencap at all, it only states that it "includes the entire game in both portrait and landscape PDFs as well as .mobi and .epub files compatable with the Kindle and other ereaders".

Comment: @recognizer — Yes. You have to buy it before you get the download links shown in the screenshot.

Comment: Ah, strange that they don't list it in the item description. I already picked up the book + PDF from Burning Wheel, and it evidently doesn't include any of the extras, so I guess the thing to do is pick up the Compendium Classes a la carte from Drive Thru.

Answer (score 23):

On the [Dungeon World](http://www.dungeon-world.com/) website, there is a [Downloads](http://www.dungeon-world.com/downloads/) section.

The [Play Kit](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3269630/dwdotcom/Dungeon_World_Play_Sheets.pdf) *"Includes character sheets, reference sheets, and GM sheets. Everything you need to play."*

Other downloads available include a new class, adventure seeds, and the very good [Dungeon World Guide](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3269630/dwdotcom/eon-guide/Dungeon%20World%20Guide%20pdf%20version%201.2.pdf), which helps those accustomed to dice-heavy RPGs to "get" Dungeon World.